# Ошибки "Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in ..."

Tags: php

> `Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in /home/user4092/html/XO4U.BIZ/admin/Product.admin.php on line 144`
>
> `Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in /home/user4092/html/XO4U.BIZ/admin/Product.admin.php on line 185`
>
> `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/user4092/html/XO4U.BIZ/admin/Product.admin.php:144) in /home/user4092/html/XO4U.BIZ/admin/Product.admin.php on line 244`

Что делать? как их убрать?

Comment: Наблюдая данные ошибки, логично было бы залезть в указанные файлы в нужные строки и разобраться с "корнем зла".

Comment: вроде понял в чем ошибка....мой хост виной...старые функции пхп не распознает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Виной не хост, который "не распознает старые функции", виной тому код магазина, который их использует.

Решение - замените везде `split` на `preg_split`(если первый аргумент - регулярка) или `explode` (если первый аргумент - строка).

Отличить строку от регулярки довольно просто, регулярка страшно выглядит, вроде `"/;\s*/"`, а explode часто делают по символу (`":"` или `"|"`).

Comment: заменил на explode так посоветовал хостер все ок...
строки вот `$delete_fotos = explode(',', $_POST['delete_fotos']);`
и вот `$related_products = explode(',', $this->item->related);`
правильно?

Comment: Скорее всего, правильно)

Answer (score 0):

Эти функции старели и больше поддерживаться не будут. Лучше их не использовать, а чтобы скрыть ошибки, попробуйте указать а самом начале php кода error_reporting(0);

Comment: Хороший совет :D